# "=SUMIF" Formula not working with 00/:00 formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Good Morning,

I have a spreadsheet I am working on and need to have the total time spent at a location automatically be calculated depending on the start and end time. It works if I keep the formatting for all the columns as "hh:mm", however I wanted to change the formatting to "00/:00" so I don't have to worry about using the colon key and can just enter the numbers (the spreadsheet needs to be updated quickly and preferably with only having to use one hand).

When I change the formatting, the auto sum quits working. Any ideas, or is there a different way I can have the colon be entered automatically without having to worry manually entering it? I've also attached a photo of what I am referring to.

[image: Photo]

Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you want to write a replacement for the function =DATEDIFF

Answer (score 0):

Excel stores time as a decimal of a day.  By using a custom format Excel is storing the number as whole numbers.

So to get the correct sum we need to parse the number into hours and minutes and divide by there respective parts:

Hours:

```
INT(Range/100)/24
```

Minutes

```
MOD(range,100)/(24*60)
```

Using SUMPRODUCT we can iterate the range adding the results:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((D1:D8="x")*((INT(C1:C8/100)/24+MOD(C1:C8,100)/(60*24))-(INT(B1:B8/100)/24+MOD(B1:B8,100)/(60*24)))
```

Which converts the whole number displayed as time to the appropriate double that Excel can render as time.

[image]